# uninitialized constant ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard::Validateable (NameError) - in Spree shop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, activemerchant

i'm new in rails. Today i tried deploy my shop(SpreeShop) to new production server, but somthing was wrong. I have foolowing problem with some gem: activemerchant (1.34.1).

Bellow is my stack trace.

```
uninitialized constant ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard::Validateable (NameError)
  /home/dp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@dp/gems/activemerchant-1.34.1/lib/active_merchant/billing/credit_card.rb:51:in `<class:CreditCard>'
  /home/dp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@dp/gems/activemerchant-1.34.1/lib/active_merchant/billing/credit_card.rb:49:in `<module:Billing>'
  /home/dp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@dp/gems/activemerchant-1.34.1/lib/active_merchant/billing/credit_card.rb:6:in `<module:ActiveMerchant>'
  /home/dp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@dp/gems/activemerchant-1.34.1/lib/active_merchant/billing/credit_card.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/dp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@dp/gems/activemerchant-1.34.1/lib/active_merchant/billing.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/dp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@dp/gems/activemerchant-1.34.1/lib/active_merchant.rb:56:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/dp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@dp/bundler/gems/spree-3a3652adb1e8/core/lib/spree/core.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/dp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@dp/bundler/gems/spree-3a3652adb1e8/core/lib/spree_core.rb:1:in `require'
  /home/dp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@dp/bundler/gems/spree-3a3652adb1e8/core/lib/spree_core.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/dp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@dp/bundler/gems/spree-3a3652adb1e8/lib/spree.rb:1:in `require'
  /home/dp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@dp/bundler/gems/spree-3a3652adb1e8/lib/spree.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/dp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
  /home/dp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
  /home/dp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
  /home/dp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
  /home/dp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
  /home/dp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
  /home/dp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
  /home/dp/dp/releases/20150607162220/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/dp/dp/releases/20150607162220/config/environment.rb:2:in `require'
  /home/dp/dp/releases/20150607162220/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
  config.ru:3:in `require'
  config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
  /home/dp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@dp/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
  /home/dp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@dp/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
  config.ru:1:in `new'
  config.ru:1:in `<main>'
  /home/dp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@quiselle/gems/passenger-4.0.26/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:105:in `eval'
  /home/dp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@dp/gems/passenger-4.0.26/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:105:in `preload_app'
  /home/dp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@dp/gems/passenger-4.0.26/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:150:in `<module:App>'
  /home/dp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@dp/gems/passenger-4.0.26/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /home/dp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@dp/gems/passenger-4.0.26/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'
```

Do you have any idea how to resolve this problem??? I was read another post with similar problems but nothing wasnt helpfull....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the same issue detailed at https://github.com/Shopify/active_utils/issues/57 .

The fix for the issue was included into [active_merchant gem on Jan 15th, 2015](https://github.com/Shopify/active_merchant/commit/bae5e53b4d3e67ce239227382a9715cf05ea4457) and is available in activemerchant versions `1.47.0` or higher.

So to fix the issue on your rails app, update the activemerchant gem version. The steps would be as follows:

1. Modify `Gemfile` and set the active_merchant gem version with `gem 'activemerchant', '1.50.0'`
2. Run `bundle install`

Any version of activemerchant gem higher than `1.47.0` can be used.

#### Update

The [active_merchant-payu](https://github.com/estrai/active_merchant-payu/blob/84fb9bed071cf9ee4c285d6d1b7ca1ef0897cccc/active_merchant-payu.gemspec#L15) gem doesn't depend on any specific version of `activemerchant`. Run `bundle update` to force it to use the latest version of `activemerchant` gem.

Comment: ok, but i'm using gem from: https://github.com/estrai/active_merchant-payu, what do you thing what is wrong with my gems?

Answer (score 6):

The uninitialized constant ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard::Validateable issue is with the version of `active_utils` gem. Version 3 throws the error; version 2 does not. You need to set the gem version in your Gemfile.

```
# Gemfile
gem 'active_utils',  '2.0.2'
gem 'activemerchant', '~> 1.32.1', require: 'active_merchant'
```